# Numpy too slow when dealing with slices of the third axis of large files

Tags: performance, numpy, indexing, large-files

I am working with large files (greater than 8gb) of 8-bit 3D microtomography data and I need to plot slices of this image in different axis called by the user through a scroll bar so I will use matplotlib for this. But when I try to access the third axis numpy get really slow. Is there any other way to do this more efficiently?

This is my code for access data slices and the time to get maximum value for each axis:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

image1 = 'tomo-2048x2048x2048_8bit.b'

fd = open(image1, 'rb')
width = 2048
height = 2048
slices = 2048
img = np.memmap(image1, dtype=np.uint8, shape=(slices, width, height))
fd.close()

valinit = 1024
s = []
for i in xrange(3):
    s.append([slice(valinit-1, valinit, None) if j == i else slice(None) for j in xrange(3)])

for i in xrange(3):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    print(img[s[i]].squeeze().max())
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Run time: %f") %(stop - start)
```

Output:

```
202
Run time: 0.014847
255
Run time: 0.026879
255
Run time: 92.322633
```

Comment: Looks normal to me. You have to read way more of the file for the third operation than for the first two, since the first two operations read large contiguous chunks and the third operation reads scattered bytes.

Comment: If you want to speed things up, you'll need to change things so you aren't reading every 2048th byte of a giant file. Changing your program this way will require more context than we have.

Comment: Can you save in a format such as DICOM or NIfTI and use a purpose-built medical imaging viewer, like MRICron, etc.

Comment: This will integrate a local tomography control system that needs to be implemented within python but I will certainly look for other specialized medical libraries within python.